# Can I set the connection string for custom session state mode in global.asax file?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

Can I set the connection string for custom session state mode in global.asax file?
I cannot hard code the connection string in the webconfig file. ,I will get the connection string at runtime,Can i set the connection string for custom sessionmode/sqlserver session mode in the global.asax file(like in application statrevent, or aquirerequeststate event.If YES How to do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to modify this setting dynamically once the application has started. A possible workaround as proposed in [this article](http://www.sneal.net/blog/CommentView,guid,0e9ef299-ee12-4b32-8506-21b03862248a.aspx) is to test in the Application_Start if the connection string needs to be set and if yes then modify web.config which will cause the application domain to reload.

IMHO a better way to manage different connection strings among different environments is to have a step in your build process that does the necessary modifications to `web.config` before deploying.